# Unvoiced /dʒ/ and /ʒ/ in word final position

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

It seems to me that both /dʒ/ and /ʒ/ become voiceless (or almost) when they occur in word final position. Is this true?

Examples:

age, wage, courage, judge

garage, sabotage, collage, mirage

Does this happen due to the process of devoicing? If so, and as a result of this process, do the example words above lose all of their vocal fold vibration, or do they only lose some of it?

If the words above are only partially devoiced (don't lose all of their vocal fold vibration), how should they be pronounced in consequence? Can they be compared to a musical note that has to be played piano or pianissimo?

Comment: Please specify whether you have a particular brand of English in mind. The Brits pronounce garage "GAR-ridge." Is the second of the three consonants in the word "exit" voiced or unvoiced? Is it played pianissimo or forte? I'm thoroughly confused now. I don't remember ever hearing anyone saying "couraitch" or "mirash." Please clarify.

Comment: @Ricky I think that Luke is asking about the very last sound in *mirage* -- the final consonant is voiced to start with and ends up an almost unvoiced /ʃ/.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I don't know. Here's a link, click on the sound button, you'll get a velvety-sounding mezzo. It's voiced, all of it http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mirage?s=t

Comment: It's certainly true that English speaker distinguish between the words *etch* and *edge*, and *batch* and *badge*.

Comment: That would depend on one's financial situation, the quality of drinks at one's pub, and one's willingness to consume those.

Comment: @Ricky My answer might help clear that up. It'll tend to be voiced or unvoiced according to the following sound. It's very difficult for us to tell just by listening to the sound at the end of the word whether it's voiced or not. Our brains tell us that if the preceding vowel is long then it's voiced (we pay no attention to the actual consonant itself). :)

Comment: @Ricky [Just got back, hence the delay] That pronunciation is distinctly American. Brits tend to put the accent on the first syllable (for a start) and -- possibly because of that -- the last sound is devoiced, especially when said in isolation and followed by silence. As Araucaria has demonstrated in his answer.

Comment: Despite @Araucaria's scientific answer, at least in AmE, it feels like no there is no devoicing, that one would say and hear the difference between garage and garatch, age and aytch, collage and collash. mirage and mirash.

Comment: @Mitch I think that would be the clipping of the vowel that's tricking your brain. It will certainly *feel* like it's a voiced sound. So these words will all still be clearly distinguishable. That's the theory/science anyhow :)

Comment: @Araucaria Sure, I get the science but does that mean (well I think you said it in your answer) that it's the same for all word final voiced consonants? They still _feel_ different, like 'bob' and 'bop' (for stops, there's gotta be more aspiration for the unvoiced, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voiced obstruents - the plosives /b, d, g/; the affricate /dʒ/; the fricatives /v, ð, z/ and /ʒ/ - all undergo devoicing when adjacent to unvoiced sounds, including when next to silence.

They may sometimes be fully devoiced all the way through. However, they tend to be devoiced at the beginning of the consonant if preceded by an unvoiced sound or at the end if followed by an unvoiced sound. In the parametric diagram below the line for vocal fold vibration (voicing) is flat when there's no voicing and wavy when there is.

[image]

For the word *bond* said in isolation, we can see that the beginning of the /b/ and the end of the /d/ are both devoiced. In a more detailed parametric diagram, we might put the little circle currently under the b and the d as a superscript to the right or left of the consonant to indicate which side is devoiced.

If the consonant is at the end of a word but followed by a voiced sound there will be no devoicing. This type of devoicing is an assimilatory effect, meaning that the consonant is taking on qualities from the sounds next to it. If there is no voiceless sound next to the consonant, it won't normally become devoiced.

Have a look at the waveform below for the words *news items* taken from a BBC radio news broadcast:

[image]

Here, the dark black fuzz that we see at 3 and 4 (the red numbers on the diagram) shows voiceless sound. The kind of wavy (periodic) line that we can see from the beginning of the word up till the beginning of 2, is voiced sound. That kind of regular repeating pattern there is what gives us the impression that a sound has musical pitch. This, essentially,  is what voicing is. Now the transcription for *news item* is like this: /njuz aɪtəmz/. Notice that there are two /z/s here/. The first is in between two vowel sounds. The second, at the end of the second word, precedes silence. Now, if you look at 1 on the the diagram you will see that the first z is voiced all the way through. That wavy pattern carries on going all the way through the z section. However, if you look at 4, which represents the z at the end of the word next to silence, you will see that it is a messy smudge of black. This is because it is nearly entirely devoiced.

In short then, a /ʒ/ at the end of a word will become devoiced when not followed by another voiced sound. So will a voiced obstruent at the beginning of a word too, if not preceded by another voiced sound. (Only one word in English begins with the consonant /ʒ/ - the word *genre*).

**Note to learners**

It is not necessary to try and artificially recreate these types of devoicing effects. In fact, it will be harmful for your English. English speakers don't listen to (and cannot hear, unless they are specially trained) whether a consonant has voicing or not. We understand whether a sound is a /z/ or an /s/ because of other sounds in the word, not because of the /z/ or /s/ itself. An /s/ at the end of a syllable will cause the vowel to be shortened (this will happen in almost any language). This does not happen with /z/ - whether or not the /z/ has become devoiced. If you try and substitute in an unvoiced /z/, you will end up putting in an /s/ instead, which will affect the vowel and may lead to misunderstandings  - and a very strange accent. Just use a normal /z/ and the rest will take care of itself.

---

**Notes:**

<sub>The technical term for consonants that are usually voiced is *lenis*. The technical terms for sounds that are usually unvoiced is *fortis*. I haven't used these terms here, because there was enough new jargon already for unfamiliar readers.</sub>

---

**References**

<sub>The parametric diagram is from the [*Speech Internet Dictionary*](http://blogjam.name/sid/?page_id=4478).</sub>

<sub>The waveform is from [*Swphonectics.com*](http://swphonetics.com/praat/tutorials/understanding-waveforms/speech-waveforms/). Courtesy of both Sydney Wood and SWPhonetics.</sub>

<sub>Both were accessed on 21 November 2015.</sub>

Comment: The vowel length certainly plays a large part in decoding the phoneme. But I would think the voiced/unvoiced quality must also play some role in our decoding the phoneme. Otherwise, Americans wouldn't have any more trouble that Brits distinguishing *bidder* and *bitter* (and we do).

Comment: Dude, you're scaring me. Actually, it's a very good point: we're conditioned to detect key sounds only, and simply assume the rest. On a larger scale, our brains are also conditioned to look for key _words_ only in a sentence, and form an opinion about the rest without listening to it. Which leads me to believe that we expect others to speak exclusively in stock phrases, and those others expect us to do the same. The eerie part here is that there's no room for actual _thinking_ in this picture: it's all just reflexes. Now that's reassuring.

Comment: @PeterShor I believe that the reason that the US one is more likely to cause problems there is that there's a lack of aspiration which Brits would get following the /t/. Because aspiration is basically a quality of the vowel following the /t/ before the voicing kicks in there's no aspiration after a voiced /t/. So again, weirdly, we're seeing an effect on neighbouring EDIT: vowels. What I do know is that in BE at least, you can change people's perception of a voiced sound by chopping the vowel before it ...

Comment: @PeterShor However, I'm not an expert on Gen Am. It would be interesting to see what the actual data shows ... (for those speakers who use a voiced allophone of /t/ intervocalically).

Comment: @Ricky Yeah, it's kind of weird but wonderful, ain't it!

Answer (score 2):

> ... how should they be pronounced... Can they be compared to a musical
>   note that has to be played piano or pianissimo?

The final consonants in those words are all voiced.  *The voicing tends to be accompanied by a prolonged preceding vowel and unvoiced consonants by a shortened preceding vowel. Concentrate on that vowel, not on the consonants.*

I heard Angela Merkel the other day use the English word "fans" (which I suppose has become a loan-word in German). She pronounced it "fence". It's a good example of how the vowel is affected in English:

faaanz

fence

P.S. So, to take up your analogy, imagine the choir director telling the singers to hold the note which corresponds to the vowel and then in your mind's eye see the director bringing his two fingers and thumb together gently, to reflect how the "voiced obstruent" closes off the sound unabruptly.

Comment: @That's a bit of a wide-spread misconception. The voiced consonant doesn't lengthen the preceding vowel, exactly; it's that unvoiced (i.e. fortis) consonants cause the vowel to be clipped (i.e. reduced). So the /i:/ in *bead* is ever so slightly shorter than the /i:/ in *bee*. The /i:/ in *beat* however is about half the length of the /i:/ in *bead*. :)

Comment: The vowel in my *bead* is longer than the vowel in my *bee*. But I agree about *beat*.  I've reworded to remove the implication of causality.  The vowel in my *bees* is longer than the vowel in my *bee*.

Comment: Do you have a slightly palatal offglide on *bee* but not on *be*?

Comment: This fella knows how to compromise: "Because of the influence of voicing on vowels —they have shorter duration before a voiceless obstruent— English has a cline of four durational patterns illustrated in *bead, beat, bid, bit*." http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~odden/Vowel%20Length.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the delay, have been doing an answer for this question. I think *bee* and stressed *be* are the same for me, but its difficult to tell if that's how I actually normally talk. Yes that sounds like a good description from OS.